# tensorflow on tx2 protobuf

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, nvidia

Hi i have installed tensorflow using
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038957/jetson-tx2/tensorflow-for-jetson-tx2-/post/5278617/#5278617

when i run the python script i get the following error:

```
libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc".)
Aborted (core dumped)

```
pip show protobuf i get Version: 3.6.1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /home/nvidia/vitualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: setuptools, six
Required-by: tensorflow-gpu, tensorboard
```

someone have some ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Very common with PIP. You probably have multiple installations (i.e., a local PIP install and the system install) and what PIP reports is different from what is used at build time by some other script. This is very environmental, but for a start you need to look at what is throwing this error exactly and then find out where it thinks the modules it needs is installed. There is a fair amount of discussion on SO already about this, but you will have dig around a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it worked. In the end i have to `import tensorflow` at the beginning of the python file. No other solution worked for me except this one.

I do not understand why. 
If someone know the answer can you please explain me why?

Thanks